# read plist iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I am trying to read a plist file using this -

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:SettingsFilePath];

NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSArray *array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:nil];
```

but its not working.. is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this way -

```
  NSArray *arr= [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath` to load it.